# jQuery Fade In Fade Out turning image black in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I am using jQuery to fade in and fade out images, and it works find in every browser except for IE8 in Windows 7.  It will turn the image black with a gradient, then switch to the correct color.  How do I go about fixing this?

http://webapps.easy2.com/ce/ext1108/iris_alarm.html

Comment: The problem is PNG's alpha channel and transparency... Plenty of web resources regarding this issue.